# using James MailServer to Create a MailingSystem deplayed on Glassfish

Tags: apache, jakarta-mail, mail-server, james, glassfish-4

I am attempting to make a mailing system using a local mailserver (Apache James Mailserver), also using the JavaMail and JFA APIs
Can i do that ? any body has an idea about the ideal way to accomplish such a goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.  Yes, it's a lot of work.  If you want to do most of the work yourself, you can find some [simple example programs on the JavaMail project page](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Samples).  You'll find some more complete programs on the [JavaMail third party products page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/third-party-136965.html).

Answer (score 0):

You probably can. Apache James comes packaged as a WAR, but you will have to build it. Just get the sources from [1] with SVN or git [2]. Build them with Maven and check under app/target directory. You will see a WAR file along with the normal standalone, zip packaged distribution.

[1] http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/james/server/trunk/

[2] https://github.com/apache/james